# setting charset on a c webserver?

Tags: c, character-encoding, webserver, backend, httpserver

So, i need to to a server that returns the charset ( between other stuffs)
and im not sure what should be the value as im working in a c web server.

For now what the server do is only returns images and html, its not harder than that, but what should be the value of charset in  the general header response of the server?

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK  
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8  
Content-Length: XXXX
```

I've read that i can set whatever i want as C manage ASCII.

Any advice?

Comment: If you are not sure, you don't have to show charset in the header. The browser (or other viewer) will manage to handle the files.

Comment: but it which case i have to show it?